# Select DOM elements by data attribute using array of integers?

Tags: arrays, queryselector

If I have this: `[ 2, 5, 6, 8, 9 ]`.

And I need to select all table rows with a data attribute like "data-id=n" that has a value contained in the array.

What would be the most efficient way?

Imagine: `let rows = document.querySelector("#table tr data-id=[ 2, 5, 6, 8, 9 ]")` ... man, wouldn't that be lovely?

I just slammed this together:

```
...
        for ( const key in flags ) {
            let arr = flags[ key ].records;

            arr.forEach( id => {
                let row = autotable.querySelector('.autotable-row[data-id="' + id + '"] td.' + key);

                if ( row ) {
                    row.classList.add(flags[ key ].flag);
                }
            });
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the array to create your selector:

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll([2, 5, 6, 8, 9].map(id => `tr[data-id="${id}"]`).join(','));

console.log([...rows]);
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr data-id="1"></tr>
  <tr data-id="2"></tr>
  <tr data-id="3"></tr>
  <tr data-id="4"></tr>
  <tr data-id="5"></tr>
  <tr data-id="6"></tr>
  <tr data-id="7"></tr>
  <tr data-id="8"></tr>
  <tr data-id="9"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, definetely more elegant than my own whacked together solution.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Firstly, Set a new `var selectors` as an empty array. By looping through every number/data-id from your array you will construct your selector like in the snippet below.

You will push that selector to your `selectors` array like this:    `selectors.push('tr[data-id="' + arrays[i] + '"]')`

Finally, just select your rows by assigning the value of selectors to the action: `document.querySelectorAll(selectors);`

```js
var arrays = [2, 5, 6, 8, 9];
let selectors = [];
  
for(var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
  selectors.push('tr[data-id="' + arrays[i] + '"]')
}

let rows = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
console.log(rows);
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr data-id="1"></tr>
 <tr data-id="2"></tr>
  <tr data-id="3"></tr>
   <tr data-id="4"></tr>
    <tr data-id="5"></tr>
     <tr data-id="6"></tr>
      <tr data-id="7"></tr>
       <tr data-id="8"></tr>
        <tr data-id="9"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of stringifying the array and then converting it back into an array with `.split()`? Why not loop over `arrays` without the first 3 lines?

Comment: You are right, that was so unnecessary actually. I just editted my code.